# How can I update some fields of an embedded object using mongoose's findOneAndUpdate method and not lose the other fields?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

```
 router.put('/experience/update/:exp_id',
    auth,
    async (req, res) => {

        const {
            title,
            company,
            location,
            from,
            to,
            current,
            description
        } = req.body;

        const newExp = {};
        newExp._id = req.params.exp_id;

        if (title) newExp.title = title;
        if (company) newExp.company = company;
        if (location) newExp.location = location;
        if (from) newExp.from = from;
        if (to) newExp.to = to;
        if (current) newExp.current = current;
        if (description) newExp.description = description;

        try {
            let profile = await Profile.findOne({ user: req.user.id });

            if (profile) {
                //UPDATE Experience
                profile = await Profile.findOneAndUpdate(
                    { user: req.user.id });
                const updateIndex = profile.experience.map(exp => exp._id).indexOf(req.params.exp_id);

                profile.experience[updateIndex] = newExp;
                    console.log('Experience updated!')
            }
            await profile.save();
            res.json(profile);

        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error.message);
            res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
        }


    }
)
```

I am using the findOneAndUpdate method to update the experience field inside a profile mongoose model.
After accesssing the endpoint, I put the updated details, for eg. company and location. But I lose all the other fields. So how can I update only select fields while others remain unchanged ?

Below is the profile schema:

```
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const ProfileSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    user: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'user'
    },
    company: {
        type: String
    },
    website: {
        type: String
    },
    location: {
        type: String
    },
    status: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    skills: {
        type: [String],
        required: true
    },
    bio: {
        type: String
    },
    githubusername: {
        type: String
    },

    experience: [
        {
            title: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            },
            company: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            },
            location: {
                type: String
            },
            from: {
                type: Date,
                required: true
            },
            to: {
                type: Date,
            },
            current: {
                type: Boolean,
                default: false
            },
            description: {
                type: String,
            }
        }
    ],
    education: [
        {
            school: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            },
            degree: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            },
            fieldofstudy: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            },
            from: {
                type: Date,
                required: true
            },
            to: {
                type: Date,
                required: true
            },
            current: {
                type: Boolean,
                default: false
            },
            description: {
                type: String,
            }
        }
    ],
    social: {
        youtube: {
            type: String,

        },
        twitter: {
            type: String,

        },
        facebook: {
            type: String,

        },
        linkedIn: {
            type: String,

        },
        instagram: {
            type: String,

        }
    },
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});

module.exports = Profile = mongoose.model('profile', ProfileSchema);
```

Comment: which fields do you lose, fields of profile or fields of experience you are updating ?

Comment: I am losing all the fields inside experience, other than those which I'm updating

Comment: I manually checked for experience if it holds a value or not. If yes, then leave it alone. I just used else for all parameters. If there's a better way please suggest.

Comment: As I can see your experience is an array lke [exp1, exp2, exp3...], Here If you will update exp2 as you are doing in your code, the entire object will be replced by the new object, In case you want to replace some part of your exp like company you have to do it like profile.experience[updateIndex].company = newCompany; (I don't work with mongoose but raw mongo and this is how mongo works)

Comment: Also please consult with the documentation of mosgoose, It might tell you the right way of updating certain fields of an object in an array. But the idea remain the same, The update object will be replaced entirely, it will not be merged with the existing one.

Comment: @humble_wolf Yeah I did the same for now. I'm sure there be a way in mongoose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some problems in your code.

1. You are passing only one argument to `findOneAndUpdate`. Ideally the syntax is `findOneAndUpdate(filter, update)`. So basically you need to pass update query as 2nd argument.

```
profile = await Profile.findOneAndUpdate(
                    { user: req.user.id });
```

2. In below code you are modifying the profile object and saving it. Which is not required. And this is also the reason why you are losing fields.

```
 const updateIndex = profile.experience.map(exp => exp._id).indexOf(req.params.exp_id);

                profile.experience[updateIndex] = newExp;
                    console.log('Experience updated!')
            }
            await profile.save();
```

**Solution-**

We need to figure out the `update` part of `findOneAndUpdate(filter, update)`.

Here is the update query -

```
db.collection.update({
  "user": "5f96dc85ac5ae03160a024a8",
  "experience._id": "5f9826c3a3fa002ce0f11853"
},
{
  "$set": {
    "experience.$": {
      "current": false,
      "_id": "5f9826c3a3fa002ce0f11853",
      "title": "Senior developer",
      "company": "Morgan Stanley",
      "location": "Pune",
      "from": "2017-04-30T18:30:00.000Z",
      "to": "2020-07-08T18:30:00.000Z",
      "description": "testing"
    }
  }
})
```

Try it [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/U11aHfz6gFT)

**Trying Mongoose way :**

```
const filter = { user: req.user.id, "experience._id": req.params.exp_id }
const update = { $set: { "experience.$": newExp } }
profile = await Profile.findOneAndUpdate(filter,update);
```

Comment: I can write a mongo query for you. You can then convert it mongoose. Please provide a sampe document.

Comment: [link](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1bsq-YJabEx8jQY5xcHxYN9NcXEmK2PNwYEy2Y-5R000/edit?usp=sharing)  I have attached a drive link for sample doc.

Comment: Also tried to add mongoose code. Can you upvote the answer.

Comment: Is there some problem in the solution? You accepted the answer and undo it?